# Simple Html/CSS/JS page doesn't work on Codepen.io?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Okay, I made a tumblr powered gallery for a client, and I was so happy with it I decided I'd make a little demo on codepen.io of it so other folks could see it.
But mysteriously it doesn't work at all? I added a code snippet here and as you can see it works fine, why not on codepen? Here's a link. http://codepen.io/StuffieStephie/pen/eJMXov It's the same code as below, what gives!?

```js
 $(document).ready( function() {
// If tumblr is down or something, show this message
  if (typeof tumblr_api_read === 'undefined') {
 $('#artHolder').html('<h2>Whoops!</h2><p class="center">We seem to be having some technical difficulty with our gallery. <br/> Sorry for the inconvenience.  In the meantime, please visit our <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/">Facebook</a> or our <a target="_blank" href="http://tumblr.com/">Tumblr</a> to see our latest works. </p><h4> If the problem persists, please let us know at <a href="mailto:webmaster@example.com">webmaster@example.com</a></h4>');
} 
  // Otherwise show the gallery
  else {
for (var i=0;i<tumblr_api_read.posts.length;i++) {
    var thisPost = tumblr_api_read.posts[i];

    $('#artHolder').append("<a class='gallery' href='" + thisPost["photo-url-1280"] + "' title='" + thisPost["photo-caption"] + "'><img src='" + thisPost["photo-url-250"] + "' longdesc='" + thisPost["photo-url-1280"] + "'></a>");
  
}
$('#artHolder').imagesLoaded( function() {
$('#artHolder').magnificPopup({
  delegate: 'a', // child items selector, by clicking on it popup will open
  type: 'image',
  gallery:{enabled:true}
});

        $("#artHolder").masonry();
}); //END LOADED
  } //END ELSE STATMENT
  
}); //END ON DOC READY
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
}
#artHolder{
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
a{
  text-decoration: none!important;
}
h1{
  text-align: center;
  font-family:'Quicksand';
}
.gallery {
 padding: 0 !important;
 line-height: 0;
 font-size: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
display: inline;
float: left;
 background: #FFF;
 transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
   border-radius: 10px;
    transform: scale(.9);
    width: 250px;

}
.gallery img{
  padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
figcaption a {
 color:#00ADDC;
 -o-transition:.5s;
  -ms-transition:.5s;
  -moz-transition:.5s;
  -webkit-transition:.5s; 
  transition:.5s;
}
figcaption a:hover {
 color:#FEE4FD;
}
figcaption blockquote {
 display: inline;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
figcaption p {
 display: inline;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 5px;
}
.gallery:hover {
 transform: scale(1);
 box-shadow: 0 15px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 border-radius: 0;
}
.gallery:hover img{
 border-radius: 0;
}
.clearfix:after {
 visibility: hidden;
 display: block;
 font-size: 0;
 content: " ";
 clear: both;
 height: 0;
 }
* html .clearfix             { zoom: 1; } /* IE6 */
*:first-child+html .clearfix { zoom: 1; } /* IE7 */
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>A Tumblr Powered Gallery</title>

  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:700|Montserrat:700|Open+Sans|Sniglet:400,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://s3.amazonaws.com/dimsemenov-static/dist/magnific-popup.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>


<h1>Tumblr Powered Gallery with Magnific Pop-up and Masonry</h1>
<div id="artHolder" class="clearfix"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://original-photographers.tumblr.com/api/read/json"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/imagesloaded@4.1/imagesloaded.pkgd.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/dimsemenov-static/dist/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/3.3.2/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: what exactly doesn't work? It gives an error in codepen's console `magnificPopup is not a function` but what is failing?

Comment: you're loading magnific before jquery (I'm ignoring the scripts loaded in the html, just looking at the scripts loaded in the JS panel on codepen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your order of script inclusion is in wrong, you are including *magnific* before *jQuery*. Click on gear icon in JS panel to see the scripts and in which order they are being loaded, below is the screenshot of the same.

[image]

I've tested it with correct order and it's working fine.